# Python will sometimes throw 'invalid literal for int() with base 10:' error when converting string to int and sometimes won't

Tags: python, regex, string, integer, ros

I am writing a Python ros node to read encoder data from an Arduino, and publish it as a ros topic in Python.

The Arduino is writing data fine over the serial port, but sometimes the python script won't be able to convert the string encoder data to an `int` and sometimes it will.

My code is attached below for the conversion from string to `int`:

```py
line = ser.readline().strip()
count = re.sub(r'[^-\d]', "", line)
encData = int(count)
```

Comment: What's a value of `line` the produces an invalid argument `count`?

Comment: Your regex doesn't necessarily produce a valid int as its output.  Consider for example `"123-123-123"`.  Or `"asdf"`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your strings either contain multiple hyphens or they contain no digits.

You need to create additional fallbacks for those scenarios:

```py
import re

def get_number(line):
    count = re.sub(r'^[^\d-]*(-)|-', r'\1', line) # Remove all -s other than first minus
    count = re.sub(r'[^-\d]', "", count) # remove all chars other than - and digits
    if all(c.isdigit() for c in count.replace('-','')) and count.replace('-',''):
        return int(count)
    else:
        return None
        
for s in ['1v23-1b23-1n23', '-12-a3-', 'abc', '--ddd']:
    print(get_number(s))
```

See [the Python demo](https://ideone.com/1ZZVLb). Output:

```
123123123
-123
None
None
```

I added two lines of code:

- `re.sub(r'^[^\d-]*(-)|-', r'\1', line)` - removes all chars other than digits and hyphens before the first hyphen (that is kept), and removes all other hyphens in the string
- `if all(c.isdigit() for c in count.replace('-','')) and count.replace('-',''):` - if `count` only contains digits cast the value to int and return, else, `None` is returned.